# Two theme locations for two menus, but only one is showing up

Tags: php, menus, themes

Here is what I try to achieve.

I have two menus. One is going to be a top navigation that lists all the pages, and the other one is going to list post categories.

in my header.php, I included the following code to generate menus for pages.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class' => 'mainNav',
    'theme-location' => 'Pages'
) );
```

and in the body of my index.php, I included the following code to generate menus for post categories.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme-location' => 'Categories'
) );
```

inside my function.php file, the following code is included to register theme locations so I can customize and edit menus in Wordpress dashboard.

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'Pages' => __('Pages Menu'),
    'Categories' => __('Categories Menu')
));
```

Then I created two menus and specified which menu should appear in which location.

However, the menu for pages (whose theme-location is 'Pages') is overridden by the menu for post categories (whose theme-location is 'Categories'). If I delete the menu for post categories, then the menu for pages show up.

I have been searching everywhere to see if anyone had a similar issue and resolved it and tried their solutions, but nothing has worked out so far for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theme-location` should be `theme_location` Check documentation [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

corrected code

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class' => 'mainNav',
    'theme_location' => 'Pages'
) );

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'Categories'
) );
```